# Reading a section of a line in a file in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, data-analysis

I am using python 2.7 because that is what my professor is having us use.

I am analyzing flag data and each line contains 30 attributes about each flag.

I am only concerned with the 1st and 11th-17th attributes, but am not sure how to read those in and store them without the other ones I am not concerned with.

I am also pretty new to python so this could be a simple task I am just unaware of so if any suggestions help, I really appreciate it.

```
def getColors():
    f = open('flag.data.txt')
```

An example of one line in the file:

```
Afghanistan,5,1,648,16,10,2,0,3,5,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,green,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,black,green
```

Comment: Is it csv data that you are working with? Please paste some code to show us how you are opening the file.

Comment: it could fit that, but is currently in a txt file separated by commas @DanielScott

Comment: split the data into an array and use the 11th to 17th attributes.. also it will be helpful for the community if you would show sample data

Comment: From that example line, which attributes would be the correct output? Because judging by the function name, it seems you are more likely interested in columns 0, 16, 27, and 28 (Python indexes start on zero).

Comment: Starting at 0, correct output would be: Afghanistan, 1,1,0,1,1,1,0    Those values represent the presence of the colors I am interested in, sorry for the confusion. @accdias

Answer (score 1):

Why not try:

```
def getColors():
    arr=[]
    f = open('flag.data.txt','r')
    for line in f: 
        line_arr = line.split(',')
        arr.append([line_arr[0]] + [line_arr[i] for i in range(10, 17)])
    return arr
```

Comment: That list comprehension can be simplified to ```[line_arr[0]] + [line_arr[i] for i in range(10, 17)]```, making it more intuitive... IMHO.

Comment: Great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers, I would suggest something like this so:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

attributes = []
with open('flag.data.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        data = line.strip().split(',')
        attributes.append([data[0]] + data[10:17])
```

In the end, `attributes` array will have the cleaned out data you expect.

Comment: Check out the updated version because I missed an indent on the previous one.

Comment: He's still learning python. Should have let him do it by himself

Comment: accdias I think you meant the line: `attributes.append([data[0]] + data[10:17])`

Comment: @DanielScott, nops. The op told he is interested in columns 1, 11-17, or 0, 10-16, with a zero based index, like we have in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use numpy, [np.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) can be handy for problems like these:

```
import numpy as np 
from StringIO import StringIO

data = """Afghanistan,5,1,648,16,10,2,0,3,5,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,green,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,black,green"""

result =  np.loadtxt(StringIO(data),dtype=str,delimiter=',',usecols=(0,10,11,12,13,14,15,16))
```

returns:

```
array(['Afghanistan', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0'], dtype='|S11')
```

Comment: I don't know but I think string sppliting and array slicing seem to be easier for someone who is learning.

Comment: Sure thing! :-D